# Bean population error - Querydsl

Tags: java, spring, querydsl

I've tried to populate List<> by querying with QueryDSL but it throws an error at bean population.

Here's my method;

```
@Override
    public Page<UserDTO> findByTypeQuerydsl(String filters, Pageable pageable) {
        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
        query = (JPAQuery) super.getQuerydsl().applyPagination(pageable, query);

        List<UserDTO> results = query.from(qUserDTO)
                  .innerJoin(qUser)
                  .on(qUserDTO.id.eq(qUser.id))
                  .where(qUserDTO.login.eq(filters))
                  .list(Projections.fields(UserDTO.class, qUser.id, qUser.login, qUser.firstname, qUser.lastname, qUser.dayofbirth, 
                          qUserDTO.district, qUserDTO.city));


        return new PageImpl<UserDTO>(results, pageable, results.size());
    }
```

Error is thrown at `.list` and saying;

> The method list(Projections.fields(UserDTO.class, qUser.id,
>   qUser.login, qUser.firstname, qUser.lastname, qUser.dayofbirth,
>   qUserDTO.district, qUserDTO.city)) is undefined for the type QueryBase

My **UserDTO.class;**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERDTO")
@QueryEntity
public class UserDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7860243025833384447L;

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String login;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Date dayofbirth;
    private String city;
    private String district;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    User user;

    //getters and setters

    }
```

Versions of **com-querydsl**;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using querydsl 4.x, you should use the fetch() method, this way:

```
QueryBase queryBase = new JPAQuery(qUserDTO)....
FetchableQueryBase fetchableQueryBase = (FetchableQueryBase) queryBase;
fetchableQueryBase.fetch();
```

If you really want to maintain your synthax, you should downgrade to 3.x version.

[Here](http://www.querydsl.com/releases), the release notes.

Comment: Thanks for post but when I change `list` to `.fetch()` it throws an error. Could you please show me how to convert my method exactly, just for once? @Andrea

Comment: Thanks I handle it

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using queryDSL 4 and Java 8 stream:

```
List<UserDTO> results = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager)
                .select(qUser.id, qUser.login, qUser.firstname, qUser.lastname, qUser.dayofbirth, qUserDTO.district, qUserDTO.city)
                .from(qUserDTO)
                .innerJoin(qUserDTO.user(), qUser)
                .where(qUserDTO.login.like(filters))
                .fetch()
                .stream()
                .map(c -> new UserDTO(c.get(qUser.id), c.get(qUser.login), c.get(qUser.firstname), c.get(qUser.lastname), 
                        c.get(qUser.dayofbirth), c.get(qUserDTO.district), c.get(qUserDTO.city)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```